# Erro de Insert no MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Fiz isso:

```
MongoDB Enterprise>db.Channels.insert({
... "ChannelCode" : "BT"
... "Name" : "Bartira"
... "Celphone" : "(11)971418418"
... "Endpoint" : "www.bartira.com.br"
... "TokenLogin" : "1234567890"
... "TokenLoginExpiration" : "2018-06-13T00:00:00.000Z"
... "Active" : "true"
... })
```

Ocorre esse erro:

> 2018-06-13T17:48:02.218-0300 E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: missing
>   } after property list @(shell):3:0

A chave ao que parece está correta

Comment: Faltou a vírgula nos itens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que falte a virgula separadora dos itens do hash.
Tenta assim:

```
> db.Channels.insert({
  "ChannelCode" : "BT",
  "Name" : "Bartira",
  "Celphone" : "(11)971418418",
  "Endpoint" : "www.bartira.com.br",
  "TokenLogin" : "1234567890",
  "TokenLoginExpiration" : "2018-06-13T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Active" : "true"
})
```